# Winform Designer always move a ToolMenuStrip item from private field to InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a winform project. I declare a ToolMenuStrip item in private fields as `private ToolMenuStrip menu1` and initialize as below:

```
private ToolMenuStrip menu1;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    menu1 = new ToolMenuStrip();
    ...
}
```

However, if I try to open this form in Designer in order to check its UI. Winform Designer will modify the myform.designer.cs file automatically, myform.designer.cs becomes:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ToolMenuStrip menu1 = new ToolMenuStrip();
    ...
}
```

You see, the private member property is removed and `menu1` is a temporary variable now. I don't know whether I set anything wrong but it's really wierd.

BTW, even if I delete this ToolMenuStrip item, Winform Designer will generate the *.designer.cs file each time I switch to Design View. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: I don't think so.  That file is meant to be modifiable by designer.  If you want to control it, declare it in the `Form` code (myform.cs), and add it manually, such as `this.Controls.Add(menu1)`.  You'll have to handle more yourself, but you are then free from designer overrides.

Comment: If I add a control in Design View, Designer will declare it as private in designer.cs and initialize it in InitializeComponents(). I don't see why this time Designer just changes this control to a variable in function InitializeComponents().